# FakeApplication using a specific application.conf?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

How can I create a `FakeApplication` to run my tests using my `dev.conf` instead of the default `application.conf`?

My current test consists of the following construct:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("config.file", "/path/to/dev.conf");
FakeApplication fakeApplication = fakeApplication(map);
TestServer testServer = testServer(3333, fakeApplication);
// testServer.start();
running(testServer, HTMLUNIT, new F.Callback<TestBrowser>() {
    public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

This code adapted from [the Play Framework Documentation about writing test](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFunctionalTest) throws the following Exception, as the default `application.conf` does not work on my development-system. If I uncomment `testServer.start();` I can see it even more clearly.

```
[WARN] [01/01/2013 18:36:59.505] [pool-4-thread-3] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [akka.actor.promises-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
[WARN] [01/01/2013 18:36:59.521] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [akka.actor.actions-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
[error] Test test.ApplicationTest.runInBrowser failed: Server is not started!
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]     at play.api.test.TestServer.stop(Selenium.scala:117)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.stop(Helpers.java:325)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:355)
[error]     at test.ApplicationTest.runInBrowser(ApplicationTest.java:74)
[error]     ...
```

I assume the line

```
map.put("config.file", "/path/to/dev.conf");
```

is wrong and has to be adapted. But how?

Comment: Please try `./path/to/dev.conf`.

Comment: That didn't do the trick unfortunately. Actually, I used an absolute path.

Comment: Then try `./conf/dev.conf`.

Comment: Course, I did try this too. ;-) I think I've tried all varieties of writing a path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to substitute main config with another this way. You only could override specific settings by passing a map to `fakeApplication`.

I.e. if you config contains:

```
mongodb.default.uri = ...
logger.root = ERROR
```

You can override it by placing new values inside a map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("mongodb.default.uri", "...");
map.put("logger.root", "INFO");

FakeApplication fakeApplication = fakeApplication(map);
```

Comment: Although this was not the solution I was looking for, I could workaround the problem with it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to run your test command as follows:

`play -Dconfig.file=path/to/dev.conf
test`

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out this option:

http://alexgaribay.com/2015/02/05/overwrite-settings-for-testing-in-play-framework/

Comment: Do not just add a link, extract the important information from it and add it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I did something like this to solve it:

```
  private Configuration additionalConfigurations;

  @Before
  public void initialize() {
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Config additionalConfig  =ConfigFactory.parseFile(newFile(cl.getResource("application.dev.conf").getF)));
    additionalConfigurations = new Configuration(additionalConfig);
  }
  @Test
  public void testPropertiesGetLoaded() throws Exception{

    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(additionalConfigurations.asMap())), HTMLUNIT, new F.Callback<TestBrowser>(){
      public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) throws InterruptedException {

        String specificProperty = Play.application().configuration().getString("db.ro.url");
        Logger.info("printingVar:" + specificProperty);

      }
    });
  }
```

where application.dev.conf can be whaterver config file you want to set in there.