# Loading Play File with Relative Path during Testing

Tags: playframework-2.0

After reading a value from `application.conf`, I'd like to create a `java.io.File` with that path.

```
val filePath= ConfigFactory.load().getString("filePath")
val file = application.getExistingFile(filePath).get
```

When running tests that run the above code, I get the following run-time error on the second line.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application

How can I retrieve a file in `Play` with a relative path both during application run-time & testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run it inside a FakeApplication to be able to do stuff that depend on having a running app. See the docs for more details: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to specify which `application.conf` will be used by the `FakeApplication`?

Comment: It will use the default application.conf, you can make it use another one or just provide specific settings through the constructor parameters of FakeApplication

Comment: If I read this answer correctly, then he says it's not possible to point to another `application.conf` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14116805/409976

Comment: Yeah, I jumped to conclusions about the path argument, you could probably subclass FakeApplication and override Application.configuration to provide a totally separate config though.

Comment: is it legitimate to use a `fakeApplication` if the `application` cannot be resolved? In other words, if `application` can't be read, then play is **definitely** not running? It seems hacky for me to put a `fakeApplication` in my non-test code.

Comment: But wasn't the problem appearing when you run a test? Thats where you put the fake application, not in your non-test code. 

Also, one option could be to pass the application manually to configuration instead of using the implicit, this way you could for example map over the Play.maybeApplication option instead.